# System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request

Tags: c#, macos, cocoa, xamarin, xamarin.mac

I do long task in background , it may take several minutes or hours  and I run this task periodically ..., every 30 minute with repeating task :

```
        NSTimer.CreateRepeatingScheduledTimer(SyncIntervalSeconds, (obj) =>
             {
                 DataOfNextSync = DataOfNextSync.AddSeconds(SyncIntervalSeconds);
                 System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() =>
                        {
                            syncService.FullDataSync();
                        });
             });
```

inside "fullsync" I use **HttpClient** and **SQLite** database, getting some information from server and put it in my database and saving some files on the disk

Generally everything works fine, but in some cases, I don't know why (often when mac is sleeping, not always), task stops with following error message:

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request ---> System.Net.WebException: Error: NameResolutionFailure
>     at System.Net.WebConnection+d__16.MoveNext () [0x0002c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/5.0.0.0/src/Xamarin.Mac/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebConnection.cs:137 
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/5.0.0.0/src/Xamarin.Mac/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/5.0.0.0/src/Xamarin.Mac/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/5.0.0.0/src/Xamarin.Mac/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/5.0.0.0/src/Xamarin.Mac/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:447 
>     at System.Net.WebConnection+d__19.MoveNext () [0x000cc] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/5.0.0.0/src/Xamarin.Mac/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebConnection.cs:259 
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/5.0.0.0/src/Xamarin.Mac/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/5.0.0.0/src/Xamarin.Mac/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/5.0.0.0/src/Xamarin.Mac/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/5.0.0.0/src/Xamarin.Mac/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:535 
>     at System.Net.WebOperation+<Run>d__57.MoveNext () [0x00052] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/5.0.0.0/src/Xamarin.Mac/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebOperation.cs:268 
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>     at System.Net.WebCompletionSource`1+d__15[T].MoveNext () [0x0008e] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/5.0.0.0/src/Xamarin.Mac/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebCompletionSource.cs:111 
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>     at System.Net.HttpWebRequest+d__241`1[T].MoveNext () [0x000b5] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/5.0.0.0/src/Xamarin.Mac/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:952 
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>     at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00018] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/5.0.0.0/src/Xamarin.Mac/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:1180 
>     at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1[TResult].FromAsyncCoreLogic (System.IAsyncResult iar, System.Func`2[T,TResult] endFunction, System.Action`1[T] endAction, System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] promise, System.Boolean requiresSynchronization) [0x0000f] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/5.0.0.0/src/Xamarin.Mac/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/FutureFactory.cs:550 
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/5.0.0.0/src/Xamarin.Mac/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/5.0.0.0/src/Xamarin.Mac/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/5.0.0.0/src/Xamarin.Mac/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/5.0.0.0/src/Xamarin.Mac/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:535 
>     at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler+d__64.MoveNext () [0x003d3] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/5.0.0.0/src/Xamarin.Mac/mcs/class/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http/HttpClientHandler.cs:402 
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>     at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler+d__64.MoveNext () [0x0046c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/5.0.0.0/src/Xamarin.Mac/mcs/class/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http/HttpClientHandler.cs:406 
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/5.0.0.0/src/Xamarin.Mac/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/5.0.0.0/src/Xamarin.Mac/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/5.0.0.0/src/Xamarin.Mac/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/5.0.0.0/src/Xamarin.Mac/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:535 
>     at System.Net.Http.HttpClient+<SendAsyncWorker>d__46.MoveNext () [0x00080] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/5.0.0.0/src/Xamarin.Mac/mcs/class/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http/HttpClient.cs:276 
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>     at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional (System.Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions) [0x00013] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/5.0.0.0/src/Xamarin.Mac/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2166 
>     at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].GetResultCore (System.Boolean waitCompletionNotification) [0x0002b] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/5.0.0.0/src/Xamarin.Mac/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Future.cs:562 
>     at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].get_Result () [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/5.0.0.0/src/Xamarin.Mac/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Future.cs:532 
>     at Aptos.Core.APIProvider.Get (System.String url, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue] headers) [0x00080] in <2162774b92f2416e98dc5d9fc831c8f3>:0 
>     at Aptos.Core.SynchronizationService.DownloadImage (SQLite.SQLiteConnection conn, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue] headers, Aptos.Core.PatientImage newimage, System.String oldRelPath, System.Boolean isImport) [0x00097] in <2162774b92f2416e98dc5d9fc831c8f3>:0 
>     at Aptos.Core.SynchronizationService.GetAllChanges (System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue] headers) [0x008ba] in <2162774b92f2416e98dc5d9fc831c8f3>:0 
>   ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request ---> System.Net.WebException: Error: NameResolutionFailure
>     at System.Net.WebConnection+d__16.MoveNext () [0x0002c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/5.0.0.0/src/Xamarin.Mac/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebConnection.cs:137 
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/5.0.0.0/src/Xamarin.Mac/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/5.0.0.0/src/Xamarin.Mac/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/5.0.0.0/src/Xamarin.Mac/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/5.0.0.0/src/Xamarin.Mac/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:447 
>     at System.Net.WebConnection+d__19.MoveNext () [0x000cc] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/5.0.0.0/src/Xamarin.Mac/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebConnection.cs:259 
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/5.0.0.0/src/Xamarin.Mac/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/5.0.0.0/src/Xamarin.Mac/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/5.0.0.0/src/Xamarin.Mac/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/5.0.0.0/src/Xamarin.Mac/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:535 
>     at System.Net.WebOperation+<Run>d__57.MoveNext () [0x00052] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/5.0.0.0/src/Xamarin.Mac/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebOperation.cs:268 
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>     at System.Net.WebCompletionSource`1+d__15[T].MoveNext () [0x0008e] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/5.0.0.0/src/Xamarin.Mac/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebCompletionSource.cs:111 
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>     at System.Net.HttpWebRequest+d__241`1[T].MoveNext () [0x000b5] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/5.0.0.0/src/Xamarin.Mac/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:952 
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>     at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00018] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/5.0.0.0/src/Xamarin.Mac/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:1180 
>     at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1[TResult].FromAsyncCoreLogic (System.IAsyncResult iar, System.Func`2[T,TResult] endFunction, System.Action`1[T] endAction, System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] promise, System.Boolean requiresSynchronization) [0x0000f] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/5.0.0.0/src/Xamarin.Mac/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/FutureFactory.cs:550 
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/5.0.0.0/src/Xamarin.Mac/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/5.0.0.0/src/Xamarin.Mac/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/5.0.0.0/src/Xamarin.Mac/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/5.0.0.0/src/Xamarin.Mac/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:535 
>     at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler+d__64.MoveNext () [0x003d3] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/5.0.0.0/src/Xamarin.Mac/mcs/class/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http/HttpClientHandler.cs:402 
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>     at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler+d__64.MoveNext () [0x0046c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/5.0.0.0/src/Xamarin.Mac/mcs/class/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http/HttpClientHandler.cs:406 
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/5.0.0.0/src/Xamarin.Mac/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/5.0.0.0/src/Xamarin.Mac/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/5.0.0.0/src/Xamarin.Mac/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/5.0.0.0/src/Xamarin.Mac/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:535 
>     at System.Net.Http.HttpClient+d__46.MoveNext () [0x00080] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/5.0.0.0/src/Xamarin.Mac/mcs/class/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http/HttpClient.cs:276 <---

Comment: `NameResolutionFailure` means the the machine can't resolve the DNS name of the host. This probably means that you aren't connected to a network that can reach the DNS server. Best strategy? Try again.

Comment: @spender thanks for answer, is it possible that mac turn off wifi when sleeping ? I see this exception, but reason is not clear. because those problem accrued several times,  in some devices.